# APScheduler job IDs: why are jobs allowed to share IDs?

Tags: python, apscheduler

I am working on an Flask application that utilises the `BackgroundScheduler`. One functionality of the app is to send a request that schedules a job at a particular date, but only if there isn't a job at that date already. So I figured I can rely on the job `id` parameter to be unique... However, it looks like it doesn't have to be.

Here is a super simple example of adding two jobs with the same `id` to the scheduler:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler

scheduler = BackgroundScheduler()


def hello():
    print "Hello!"


def goodbye():
    print "Goodbye!"

scheduler.add_job(hello, trigger='interval', seconds=5, id='1')
scheduler.add_job(goodbye, trigger='interval', seconds=5, id='1')

print scheduler.get_jobs()
print scheduler.get_job('1')
```

which outputs

```
[<Job (id=1 name=hello)>, <Job (id=1 name=goodbye)>]
hello (trigger: interval[0:00:05], pending)
```

I would have expected this to error due to conflicting IDs. But instead, both jobs are registered and when querying for the specific job ID, only the first is  returned.

Additionally, setting the `replace_existing` parameter to `True` doesn't seem to replace the job.

Am I missing something vital, perhaps configuring the job store?

Comment: Seems legit question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your scheduler has not started it adds the job to some pending_job list that doesn't have validation, it may be a bug or intended i don't know, but you can verify this by first starting the scheduler and then adding the jobs you will get `ConflictingIdError`.

Comment: It seems the reason it wasn't working was that the scheduler does not start during my unit tests!